# rails association eager loading with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, eager-loading, has-many-through

I have trouble finding a way to link to class A to E. Here are the class implied :

A has many B
B belongs to A 
B belongs to C 
A has many C through B 

C has many D
D belongs to C
D belongs to E class_name C
C has_many E through D

Ok I know it is confusing so I made a schema and I hope it is more comprehensible...

[image]

My question is how can I link the class A with the class E (that is in reality class C with a particula role). How can I use a.es (es => plural of E :s ) ?

I tried A has_many E through C (in my mind it was a good solution because A has_many C (through B) and C has_many E (through D)) but it raise an error : 
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError: Invalid source reflection macro :has_many :through for has_many :es, :through => :cs.  Use :source to specify the source reflection

I'm coding on rails V2.3.9

If you have any idea please tell me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are some plugins that extend the `:through` relationship functionality, it's not generally possible to use ActiveRecord to navigate through multiple layers at the same time. The limit is generally one `:through`, no more.

Comment: but even if I can't do directly a.es can I at least do a.cs.es (cs => plural of C, es => plural of E) and then I add a 'es' method in A that permit to do a.es.
Can you give me a link for one of these plugins please?